# What is the source for making a "Shabbos Kallah"?

Tags: history, wedding, provenance, engagement-shidduch

What is the source for making a get-together for a bride and her friends on the Shabbos before the wedding? What is the earliest record of such a minhag in the Jewish community?

Comment: It seems to come from the new non jewish costoms of "equality" and "bachelorette party"

Comment: @hazoriz I doubt it. More likely it comes from the Jewish customs of "being nice to friends" and "making the bride happy".

Comment: @DoubleAA I hope so